# Checking Any checkbox is causing all the individual checkboxes to be unresponsive

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following checkboxes on my web page:

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="ValueAnyDisable()" id="Chk0" name="Test1" value="1"  />
Any  <br />
<input type="checkbox" onclick="ValueAnyDisable()" id="Chk1" name="Test1" value="12"  />
BMW <br />
<input type="checkbox" onclick="ValueAnyDisable()" id="Chk2" name="Test1" value="11"  />
FIAT <br />
<input type="checkbox" onclick="ValueAnyDisable()" id="Chk3" name="Test1" value="13"  />
Tesla  <br />
<input type="checkbox" onclick="ValueAnyDisable()" id="Chk4" name="Test1" value="54"  />
Toyota <br />
<input type="checkbox" onclick="ValueAnyDisable()" id="Chk5" name="Test1" value="44"  />
Ford <br />
```

If someone checks the "Any" check box then I want all the other checkboxes to be checked too. If someone unchecks the "Any" checkbox then I want other checkboxes to be unselected.
This is what I tried to write in order to achieve this:

```
 function ValueAnyDisable()
        {
            const otherCheckboxes = $('[id^=Chk]:not(#Chk0)');
            if ($('#Chk0').is(':checked'))
                otherCheckboxes.prop('checked', true);
            else
                otherCheckboxes.prop('checked', false);

        }
```

the above code checks all the checkboxes when "Any" is checked and uncheck all the checkboxes when "Any" is unchecked, but after I uncheck the "Any"  checkbox, I cannot individually check any check box. All other checkboxes become unresponsive. I am creating these checkboxes in a loop and the value is coming from the database so I can only put one onclick event for all the checkboxes. The above check boxes is the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `ValueAnyDisable`, you are setting check or uncheck of all the checkboxes depending on whether `Chk0` is checked or not. There is no individual "life" for other checkboxes. By calling this same function `onclick` of all other checkboxes, in a way, you have restricted all other checkboxes to the value of `Chk0`.

Since you just need to listen for check of `Chk0` for this particular functionality, you can run a click function just for on `Chk0`, and set values of other checkboxes true or false depending on the value of `Chk0`. And since this function will be only called on `Chk0`, other checkboxes will not be restricted of their individual check actions.

```js
$("#Chk0").click(function () {
        $('[id^=Chk]:not(#Chk0)').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked')).prop('disabled', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk0" name="Test1" value="1"  />
Any  <br />
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk1" name="Test1" value="12"  />
BMW <br />
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk2" name="Test1" value="11"  />
FIAT <br />
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk3" name="Test1" value="13"  />
Tesla  <br />
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk4" name="Test1" value="54"  />
Toyota <br />
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk5" name="Test1" value="44"  />
Ford <br />
```

Comment: I am creating these checkboxes in a loop and the value is coming from the database so I can only put one onclick event for all the checkboxes. The above check boxes is the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to remove the onclick event from another input checkbox so your HTML will be look like:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="ValueAnyDisable()" id="Chk0" name="Test1" value="1" />Any  <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk1" name="Test1" value="12"  />BMW <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk2" name="Test1" value="11"  />FIAT <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk3" name="Test1" value="13"  />Tesla <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk4" name="Test1" value="54"  />Toyota <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk5" name="Test1" value="44"  />Ford <br/>
```

and your function should be:

```
function ValueAnyDisable()
    {   
        if ($('#Chk0').is(':checked')) {
                $('input').prop('checked', true);
            } else {
                $('input').prop('checked', false);
            }
    }
```

**You can also do it with ID selector.**
You can remove onclik ="ValueAnyDisable()" :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk0" name="Test1" value="1" />Any  <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk1" name="Test1" value="12"  />BMW <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk2" name="Test1" value="11"  />FIAT <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk3" name="Test1" value="13"  />Tesla <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk4" name="Test1" value="54"  />Toyota <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk5" name="Test1" value="44"  />Ford <br/>
```

**and your JQuery event change to :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Chk0').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('input').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('input').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: I am creating these checkboxes in a loop and the value is coming from the database so I can only put one onclick event for all the checkboxes.

Comment: Yes you can make a condition for loop-1 only. Like, if you are using "For loop": 
$checkbox_html = '';
for(i=0; i<array_length; i++){
 if(i==0){
  $checkbox_html .= '<input type="checkbox" onclick="ValueAnyDisable()" id="Chk<?= $i; ?>" name="Test<?= $i; ?>" value="1" />Any  <br/>'
 }
 else
 {
  $checkbox_html .= '<input type="checkbox"  id="Chk<?= $i; ?>" name="Test<?= $i; ?>" value="1" />Any  <br/>'
 }
}

Comment: @Anjali - I can help you exactly as per you requirement if you can send the loop code here. So I can update accordingly.

Comment: You can also do it without function : ValueAnyDisable. You can remove this function from all input check box and then you can use id selector : 
$('#Chk0').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  $('input').prop('checked', true);
 } else {
  $('input').prop('checked', false);
 }
});

Answer (score 1):

Improved your html a bit by adding a `<label>` tag. And created a minimal function for checkboxes change event:

```js
$(document).on('change', '[name="Test1"]', function() {
  const anyCheckbox = $('#Chk0');
  const checkboxes = $('[name="Test1"]').not(anyCheckbox);
  if ( $(this).is(anyCheckbox) ) {
    if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
      checkboxes.prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
    }
  } else {
    if ( $('[name="Test1"]:checked').not(anyCheckbox).length === checkboxes.length ) {
      anyCheckbox.prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      anyCheckbox.prop('checked', false);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk0" name="Test1" value="1">
<label for="Chk0">Any</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk1" name="Test1" value="12">
<label for="Chk1">BMW</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk2" name="Test1" value="11">
<label for="">FIAT</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk3" name="Test1" value="13">
<label for="Chk2">Tesla</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk4" name="Test1" value="54">
<label for="Chk4">Toyota</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Chk5" name="Test1" value="44">
<label for="Chk5">Ford</label>
```